# Storing Large Number Of audio resource

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm working on a iphone application project in which, i have around 500(250mb) audio files.

When i got them from studio they were in wav format, I converted them to caf(35mb).

is there any other way/format i can compress them ?

dumping 500 audio files to iphone app resource will be good?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In Storm Sim I did a folder reference for the audio samples with the files structured inside subfolders so I could keep them organized in a somewhat sane way.

Instead of using the standard get resource calls I just ask for the app's main bundle directory and the referenced folder is inside the main app folder with the appropriate subfolders under it.

Let me know if you need a code sample.